# How to avoid having Node.attributes casting attribute names to lowercase?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For a jQuery extension, I am building an option map by reading the attributes of a DOM element like this:

```
        $.each(this.attributes, function(i, att){
            option[att.name] = att.value;
        });
```

but `Node.attributes` casts all names to lowercase, while my options are case sensitive.

What is the best work around here?

Comment: Use either `option.getAttribute('name')` or make your options case-insensitive (casting the `att.value` to lowercase too).

Comment: Removed `jQuery` tag.  `this.attributes` is coming directly from the browser's DOM implementation.

Comment: @harpo: and I put it right back, since the OP is clearly *using* jQuery and therefore has it available, should a posted solution require its use (not that it *should*, but it remains an option).

Comment: HTML attributes are case-insensitive, there is no workaround. What do you need cased options for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your options to case insensative OR start using xhtml doctype.  (I suggest the former)

Node Attribute names are case insensative in HTML 5.
If you use an xHTML doctype they will be case sensative.